# how to open ms access 2007 file in ms access 2003

Tags: ms-access

how to open ms access 2007 file in ms access 2003

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to add something to Kevin...

Microsoft started using the accdb files in access 2007 (and later in 2010) and older versions does not support it.

The old versions used MDB files - Access 2003 uses MDB files.

If your file is an MDB file you just have to right click it and choose open with access 2003

if the file is accdb you should open it with access 2007 and use the save as option and choose  access 2000-2003.

There is some info here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/convert-a-database-to-the-access-2007-file-format-HA010048406.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-the-access-2007-file-format-HA010067831.aspx

Please note that going back is not always possible since there are new features in the new features that can not be translated to the old version... Just simple databases will be converted with no problem.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

That’s an easy one, you cant! Well to add a bit more your cant if it is in the new accdb format. However you can open up MDB files in office 2003 and 2007 so if you need both version to use that database it will have to be in MDB format